# Is there a KeyUp: method for flagsChanged:?

Tags: objective-c, nsresponder

I have implemented the `- (void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)theEvent` method in my application. It works fine when I hold down the [alt] key. The method only sends when the key is pressed, but not when I let it go again. The `- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent` won't be called. Is there anyway to see when the [alt] key is released?

Here is the code:

```
- (void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask)
    {
        NSLog(@"alt is down!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be seeing `-flagsChanged:` for both key up and key down events on modifier keys. Show us your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. I really need to test the code a bit more. After logging the NSEvent, I noticed that the `keyUp` method is already implemented (thanks [Jonathan Grynspan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265530/jonathan-grynspan) for pointing it out in the comment).

So now my code is:

```
- (void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask)
    {
        NSLog(@"alt is down!!!");
    }
    else if([theEvent keyCode] == 58)
    {
        NSLog(@"alt is up!!!");
    }
}
```

This now works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is broken for right alt. `NSAlternateKeyNask` is deprecated.

```c
- (void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSEventModifierFlagOption) {
        NSLog(@"alt is down!!!");
    } else if ([theEvent modifierFlags] | NSEventModifierFlagOption) {
        NSLog(@"alt is up!!!!!");
    }
}
```

Note that these events will fire on any mask change, for example if you press `alt` and then `cmd` there will be 2 "key down" alt events.